# Error in CSS to make these icons scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have these button looking links in the read. I need that div that contains them to allow you to scroll through the options. The rest of that menu needs to stay in place. I made the `<li>`s to display inline and made the `<ul>` to have the overflow scrollable. But they do not seem to scroll as intended.

[image]

I then tested with adding this as the viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

**CSS**

```
.headerNav { background-color: #333; }
.headerNav a { text-decoration: none; color: #fff; }
.headerNav ul { 
  list-style-type: none;     
  padding-left: 0; 
  height: 60px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.headerNav ul li { 
  display:inline-block; 
} 

.headerNav ul li a {
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-color: red;
  display:block;
}
```

**HTML** (Meteor project)

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="{{featuresPath}}">Features</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{sciencePath}}">Science</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{videosPath}}">Videos</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{casesPath}}">Cases</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{testimonialsPath}}">Testimonials</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my [codepen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/KJErp) which will likely change a lot.

Comment: I assume considering its for mobile a script would not be a reasonable option? (for good reason)? Also, do you need swipe functionality, as in with a user's swipe on their phone/tablet?

Comment: @NicholasHazel The maintainers of this project will not know JavaScript. So I am trying to build a version of this feature with only CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the width on the `<ul>` is causing a problem.  You also need to have `whitespace: nowrap`on the `<ul>`.

```
.headerNav ul { 
  list-style-type: none;     
  padding-left: 0; 
  overflow-y: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BFleK)**

Comment: This is going to be the only way you will get any sort of scrollability without a `script`.

Comment: In XCode iOS simulator, this looks great! for some reason on codepen, that scroll bar shows up. But this is what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**As far as I know, I don't believe this to be possible with HTML5 or CSS3 without a `script` involved somewhere or another.**

One option would be to set up a normal scrollbar as you would find on the right side of your screen, only use a horizontal one.

**If you want to implement any sort of *swipe* motion, a `jQuery` plugin or code would be necessary.**

Obviously this question is answered, but I figured I'd provide a nice plugin that will allow swipe effects on practically anything you want VERY easily for anybody else referencing the question.

#### http://www.rudrasofttech.com/swipe

Comment: I do appreciate this for future projects.